# Executing iOS Instruments UiAutomation Javascript code via Appium

Tags: javascript, instruments, appium, ios-ui-automation

I want to execute iOS Instruments UIAutomation javascript code using Appium. 
I am aware that I can execute some javascript from Appium using the following methods:

```
apmDriver.execute(driverCommand, parameters);
apmDriver.executeAsyncScript(script, args);
apmDriver.executeScript(script, args);
```

Suppose if I directly want to interact with Instruments UIAutomation by passing instruments javascript code. For example:

```
apmDriver.executeScript("var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var appWindow = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
appWindow.tabBar().buttons()[\"Unit Conversion\"].tap()",null)
```

Is it possible to do this on an iOS native app?

Comment: If by "iOS native app" you mean the app you are testing (i.e have the .app or .ipa) then yes you can do this.